# Azure container Instance: image from public docker leads to InaccessibleImage error

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I'm trying ACI service.
I decided to use as hello world image [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/modem7/docker-rickroll) public docker hub container.

In azure I selected other repository option and I put there `modem7/docker-rickroll:latest` the green check mark appeared, and I left the next tabs as default.

When creating the ACI I get the following error:
 `"message": "The image 'modem7/docker-rickroll:latest' in container group 'testaci' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."`

I expect to get the given image up and running and I tried not specifying the tag at the end of the image name or fully qualifying it like so index.docker.io/modem7/docker-rickroll:latest but same result.

It is a public container so I thought it was accessible.
How can I deploy this or other public docker hub images to ACI from Az Portal?

Comment: I think something is broken in Azure, last night I faced same issue, I was creating a container and it didn't succeed for 30 minutes and kept on downloading image from dockers. I guess you need to contact support.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and had to redo the entire Docker repo to get it work as in the solution. Think something to do with Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to create an ACI instance with modem7/docker-rickroll image, I got the same error as well.
[image]

[image]

But when I tried to deploy the same image from a different registry, I can provision it successfully.
It seems there is an issue with the registry.

I have followed the below steps and it worked for me.

**Step 1:** Pull the image, change the tag, and upload it to the personal registry to verify it in ACI.
[image]

**Step 2:** Create Azure Container Instance as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** Verify the Container Instance as shown below.

[image]

[image]

If the URL is keep on loading, check the container is started or not in the containers tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did the same as you but pushing to ACR instead. It's weird why azure block that container, it is public.

Comment: @demu, I recreated the same image in a different docker account/repository. It worked fine. Looks like there is a constraint in the container instances. Head scratcher for sure

Comment: I just stumbled on this issue too, and I can confirm that creating a new repository fixes the issue.